# Translation: Regard your neighbor’s gain as your gain, and your neighbor’s loss as your own loss

Tags: translation

I'm reading the book *Born for Love* at the moment and came across the following passage:

> In all great religions, for example, there’s an equivalent of the Golden Rule, a summary of moral teachings that suggests that considering how you would want to be treated in the same situation is a good guide to doing the right thing. From the biblical “Love thy neighbor as thyself” to the Taoist “Regard your neighbor’s gain as your gain, and your neighbor’s loss as your own loss,” to the Islamic “None of you [truly] believes until he wishes for his brother what he wishes for himself,” and the Talmudic “What is hateful to you, do not to your fellow man.

Taoism is obviously has Chinese roots, so I was trying to find this *maxim*, if you will, in Chinese. To no avail.

Everything I have found just seems to be English references back to the same (mis?)translated quote.

Is there a **proper** original quote of:

> “Regard your neighbor’s gain as your gain, and your neighbor’s loss as your own loss”

in Chinese? And what is it?

Edit:
Supposedly it's from: 太上感应篇....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 見人之得，如己之得；見人之失，如己之失。

Original text is here:

http://book.bfnn.org/books/0477.htm